# how to change root category to subcategory

Tags: category, magento-community, ce-1.8.0.0

I have a very silly issue here. what I did is I created categories and subcategories and all the main categories are now root categories ... but they should be under my main root category which is default category.

I have no idea that how to change the hierarchy of all these categories and set them as a subcategory of the default category which is set as root category in the store.

due to this, I can not see any category in the navigation.

I am using Magento 1.8 (so no drag and drop functionality I guess :( )

Answer (score 2):

The drop and drag functionality is still standard in Magento.

I created a video which you can view that shows me moving two root categories into a third root category and they become sub categories and visible on the frontend.

http://youtu.be/NAHE1SOAMMM

Also, make sure your categories are active and set to display:
[image: Active]

The video and the image were done on CE 1.8.1.0 with Magento Sample Data

Comment: No problem. Make sure to reindex and flush cache after changing these options (especially if using flat indexes). Also, please close the topic if you are 100% done with the question.

Comment: I have same problem, and I cannot drag/drop the root category to other root (default) category. I can drag/drop subcategories within same root category, but it wouldn't drag/drop a root category to other root. any ideas?